# Button alignment to the side

Tags: java, android

When I want to set the button to be from one side to another it gives me a 0.5 cm free space but I want to make it from one side to another without spaces. Here is my code so far. I made a test app and it worked so I'm trying to finish it and add some new stuff.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/back"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Main" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: remove the padding in the relativelayout, and change android:layout_width="fill_parent" to android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: that gives me an error in graphical layout:   <RelativeLayout>" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"<RelativeLayout>" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
You must supply a layout_width attribute.
You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Comment: Sorry my mistake  it's ok.

Comment: don't remove layout_width, just the padding

Comment: Thank you :D Does anybody know how to code that the image is the same as button??

Comment: an image view or a image button ? check my edits

Comment: I figured it out thanks I just need to look closely. I'm new at android and this kind of programming(mixture of graphical and standard programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the padding from the RelativeLayout parent to your button class. Also fill_parent should be replaced with match_parent for your button element.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/back"
tools:context=".Main" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/image"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```